# Iteratively write words in a textbox when not in focus and stop when in focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have a simple task to interact with an ordinary textbox based on whether it is in focus or not but am getting hung up on how to start and stop an iterative process using jQuery.

**Goal**

I have an HTML textbox that contains the data for several space-separated words in a `data-*` attribute: `<input type="text" data-queries="The big brown fox jumped" ...>`.

Whenever the textbox is not in focus (and when the page loads) I'd like the value of the textbox to change once every second, iterating over the different words in the `data-queries` attribute continuously.

As soon as the textbox is in focus I'd like the iteration to stop and the value to be blank (so the placeholder text shows).

**My code so far**

*HTML*

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" autocomplete="on">
    <label for="search"><h3 class="text-default">My Label</h3></label> 
    <input class="landing-search ml-15" data-queries="The big brown fox jumped" id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

*JS*

```
//Function that writes each string in @words one second apart
//then calls itself recursively to repeat
//Tries to "stop" by checking if selector is in focus
//but stops only after last word is reached, not immediately when in focus
    function write_to_textbox_loop(selector, words) {
            if(selector.is(":focus")) {
                return;
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
                (function(i){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        selector.val(words[i]);
                    }, 1000*i); 
                })(i);
            }

            setTimeout(function(){
                write_to_textbox_loop(selector, words);
            }, 1000*(words.length));
    }

    if($('.landing-search').length > 0) {

            data_queries = $('.landing-search').attr('data-queries').split(' ')

            //Write data-query attribute values into search textbox when not in focus
            $('.landing-search').focusout(function(){
                write_to_textbox_loop($(this), data_queries);
            });

            $('.landing-search').focus(function(){
                $(this).val('');
    });
```

As I wrote in the comments, this achieves the desired iterative affect (although I'm not sure why the recursive call with just `1000*words.length` works forever without any other increment since all the `setTimeout` calls pretty much happen right away, but it does work: when I remove focus it cycles through all the words one second apart forever).

But, when I click into the textbox and bring it into focus, it only stops once it has finished writing the last word in that loop. This makes sense because I stop with a return in a series of recursive calls but I need it to stop *instantaneously*.

How can I make my forever cycle through the words stop instantaneously when the textbox comes into focus and then start up again when it loses focus?

***EDIT:*** I thought of using `clearTimeout()` but it requires the `setTimeout` var you want to stop and I couldn't figure out the logic of how to track all the different `setTimeout()` calls I create recursively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write a little plugin, makes it more reusable

```js
$.fn.inputShow = function(opts) {
    var start = true;
    
    return this.each(function() {
     if ( opts === false ) {
            clearInterval( $(this).data('timer') );
            this.value = '';
        } else {
            var words = $(this).data('queries').split(/\b/).filter(function(x) { return x.trim().length });
            var i = $(this).data('i') || 0;
            
            if (start) this.value = words[i];
            
            $(this).data('timer', setInterval(function() {
                start = false;
                this.value = words[i+1] ? words[++i] : words[i=0];
                $(this).data('i', i);
            }.bind(this), opts || 1000));
        }
    });
}

$('.landing-search').on({
 focus : function() {
     $(this).inputShow(false); // stops it
    },
    blur: function() {
     $(this).inputShow(1000); // starts it, delay of 1000 milliseconds
    }
}).trigger('blur'); // start on pageload
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" autocomplete="on">
    <label for="search"><h3 class="text-default">My Label</h3></label> 
    <input class="landing-search ml-15" data-queries="The big brown fox jumped" id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, it works great. But, why is `bind()` necessary? Thanks again.

Comment: `bind` just sets the this-value inside the interval, so `this` is the element, not `window`, that's all

Comment: isn't the variable `start` redundant here? It is always set to `true` at the beginning, is only checked in the `else` hence `this.value = words[i]` will always hit when the `else` hits. It is set to false in the `setInterval` but isn't it always set to `true` when the function is called again?

Comment: Yes, it's always set to true the first time the function runs, it's just so it starts right away, and doesn't wait a second before it sets the value the first time